# Can I download Minecraft on a another computer but with a different username and skin?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My cousin and I would like to play minecraft pc  in a multiplayer world, just asking if I could just change the username and skin on a another computer for my cousin, or would that affect my character in the minecraft on my laptop too? ( sorry, I'm still new to this)

Answer (score 2):

This will only work if you have two different accounts, your skin is linked to your account, not the computer. So if I change my skin on this computer, and log into Minecraft on my laptop, the skin will still be changed. One account, one skin. 
If you have one account, and your cousin has one account. Then you can change the skin on your account and it would not affect your cousin's account.